# ComboBox Issue: Cannot bind to new value member

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, combobox

I'v got a combobox that I created as a user control(it's actually made up of a label, combobox and textbox). I'm trying to bind a dataset to the combobox datasource, but I keep getting an error message on ValueMember/Display member:

```
Cannot bind to the new display member - newdisplay member
Cannot bind to the new value member - parameter name: value
```

I thought I had everything coded correctly for the usercontrol:

```
   public partial class ucComboBox : UserControl
{
    #region Properties (6) 
    private bool isEditableReadOnly;
    private bool ArrVisible;
    private string _value;
    private string _name;

    public string value
    {
        get { return _value ; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}
```

I have a few other properties and events in the usercontrol but they shouldnt be the issue.

My code to bind the info:

```
  ((ucComboBox)ctrl).combobox.DataSource = info;
  ((ucComboBox)ctrl).combobox.ValueMember = "radiology_id";
  ((ucComboBox)ctrl).combobox.DisplayMember = "radiology_name";
```

It blows up whenever it hits value member, and i get the two errors stated above.  Am I missing something in my user control? Seems to me this should be working.. (fyi - the info datasource does contain the two columns)

I've tried a bunch of different tactics with no success. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: What is `info`? Are you absolutely sure that whatever is stored in there has public radiology_id and radiology_name?

Comment: i'm positive. I view the dataset just before I set it.

Comment: Is `info` a DataSet or a DataTable? If it's a DataSet you will have to set the DataSource to the desired DataTable: `DataSource = info.Tables[0];`

Comment: What **exactly** is the data-source here? Data-binding relates to the **source**, which is the one thing you haven't really told us about... Frankly the ucControlBox is irrelevant here. We need to know: what **exactly** is info?

Comment: @kevev22 or a list or a single object or a deferred list or a binding-source abstraction or...

Comment: @MarcGravell The only reason I am assuming it is actually a DataSet is because of what he said above - _I view the dataset just before I set it_

Comment: The dataset contains only the two columns i specified. I'm not an amateur and I know it's not the dataset fields that are my problem.

Comment: @Encryption Nobody here is calling you an amateur. I am just saying that I can't see anything in the code you posted that would cause the error, so it must be in some code that you haven't posted. The first thing that makes sense to check is what is `info`? I am not sure why you are so reluctant to tell us what it is. Is it literally a DataSet? Or as Marc Gravell says is it a list or a single object or a deferred list or a binding-source abstraction or something else? If you don't want to tell us that is fine but we can't help you with what we can't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved away from using a Datatset. Created a class("Facilities") that will hold an ID and Name values. Changed "info" to a List type. Then the following code worked just fine:

```
info.Add(new Facilities { ID = dr["other_facility_id"].ToString(), Name = dr["other_facility_name"].ToString() });

  ((ucComboBox)ctrl).combobox.DataSource = new BindingSource(info, null);//info;
  ((ucComboBox)ctrl).combobox.ValueMember = "ID";
  ((ucComboBox)ctrl).combobox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

No issues with binding that.

Comment: I had a class with a [Browsable(false)] attribute on my Id property and that seemed to cause ValueMember to throw this error. This is probably a bit late for this problem but others may not realise this.

Answer (score 8):

Also make sure the ID and Name properties are **Public** otherwise you get the error:
`Cannot bind to the new display member.`

Comment: thanks! you just saved me from additional hours of banging my head against this problem.

Comment: Thank you.  In my case I had a working system, and changed a few of my objects to internal rather than public.  That broke the binding, changing them back to public fixed it. Thanks again.

Comment: The property we are binding also must be Browsable, so do not add [Browsable(false)] attribute to properties you van to bind (this way).

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue while binding. I reversed the order and everything started working. 
The original code will look like this

```
  ((ucComboBox)ctrl).combobox.ValueMember = "radiology_id";
  ((ucComboBox)ctrl).combobox.DisplayMember = "radiology_name";
  ((ucComboBox)ctrl).combobox.DataSource = info;
```

Comment: worked for me, but why?? it was working while data behind value was String. When refactored to string[] - stopped working =|

Answer (score 1):

Surely the fragment of code below is going to cause an issue?

```
public string value
{
    get { return _value ; }
    set { _value = value; }
}
```

You need to name this something else e.g. comboValue.  "value" represents the implicit variable passed into a property declaration.

i.e.

```
public string comboValue
{
    get { return _value ; }
    set { _value = value; }
}
```

Comment: While naming something "value" is a bad choice, I don't think it is related

Comment: Can you show the code for the data source i.e. the info object that contains the radiology_id and radiology_name properties? (if it doesn't that will be why its not working...)

Comment: @MarcGravell - Good point; I'd never even *try* to name a property 'value' so it distracted me from the underlying missing information - what is the datasource and what properties does it have...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the property **Modifiers** of your combo to something different from **Public**.
However I will choose to implement two new public properties at the usercontrol level.
`DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` just to avoid that ugly cast.
In the set/get accessor I will reflect the values in/from the internal combo

```
public string DisplayMember
{ 
    get { return combobox1.DisplayMember; } 
    set { combobox1.DisplayMember = value;} 
} 
public string ValueMember 
{ 
    get { return combobox1.ValueMember; } 
    set { combobox1.ValueMember = value;} 
}
```

Comment: Tried this at one point, but I think I was not overriding the right names. Will work on that again.

Comment: Still doesn't like that code. Getting same error message when running through those properties...ugh.

Comment: May I ask you to show the relevant code in designer.cs of your usercontrol? Something is amiss here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a solution that may not apply to your problem, but might be helpful for others:

A property marked with the `[Browsable(false)]`-Attribute will also cause this exception when trying to bind to it.