# Getting values from combo box when connected by data source in c#

Tags: c#

I am new here. And have a big issue which I will really appreciate if you could help with.

Im developing a software which is just entering some data to the access file and retrieve it after some filtering (done by using date time pickers, radio buttons, combo boxes...etc)

When I want to update any entry I simply write a select query and add those values to relevant fields. But thing is that I cannot update my combo boxes. I got 2 of them. When I try following code it throws errors.

What can I do? pls help me out. Thanks!

```
cmb_district.ValueMember = dt1.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

I use the data source property to connect combo box with access database. It clearly has display and value members. But When query returns the value it do not update the combo box and give following error.

Cannot bind to the new value member.
Parameter name: value

Thanks. Pls help me out!

Comment: Please refer the following. This may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421546/combobox-issue-cannot-bind-to-new-value-member

Comment: Please provide more code. How are you binding the combo box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code line you provided is incorrect. `ValueMember` of the combo box should be set to the **name** of the property or column that you want to be the **value** of your selected object (unique ID for example). But you are filling the `ValueMember` with the content of a field.

When you bind the combo box in this way (setting the datasource with combination of `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`), the `SelectedValue` property of the combo box is filled with the value of `ValueMember` field of the selected row.

For example suppose that you have a DataTable with columns **ActorID**, **Name** and **BirthDate** with some data in it:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ActorID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("BirthDate", typeof(DateTime));


dt.Rows.Add(1, "Will Smith", new DateTime(1968,9,25));
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Bruce Willis", new DateTime(1955,3,19));
dt.Rows.Add(3, "Jim Carrey", new DateTime(1962, 1, 17));
dt.Rows.Add(18, "Nicole Kidman", new DateTime(1967,6,20));

ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
cb.Location = new Point(20, 100);
cb.Width = 100;

cb.DisplayMember = "Name";  // *****
cb.ValueMember = "ActorID"; // ***** The important part
cb.DataSource = dt;

Button btn = new Button();
btn.Text = "Show ID";
btn.Location = new Point(10, 140);
btn.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(cb.SelectedValue.ToString()); // **** The other important part.
    };

Form f = new Form();
f.Controls.Add(cb);
f.Controls.Add(btn);

f.ShowDialog();
```

When we read the `SelectedValue` of the combo box, it gets us the "ActorID" of the selected row.

Comment: @nilan59: You're welcome. You can show your appreciation by marking as accepted answer (and/or up-voting if you have enough reputation). Please refer to the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for more information. BTW, welcome to the StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Its like this

```
cmb_district.DataSource = dt1;
cmb_district.ValueMember = "SNO"; 
cmb_district.DisplayMember = "Name";
// where SNO and Name are column names in dt1.
```

Comment: Tanxxx.. not exactly bt it hepls.. Tanx again mate!! :D

Answer (score 0):

If yiu want to select a particular value after binding use following:

```
cmb_district.SelectedValue = dt1.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```