# Error on Combo box as User Control element

Tags: c#, user-controls

I'm creating a user control with a Combo box, Text box and a Button. When I place this User Control in a form following error occurred. `"Cannot bind to the new value member. Parameter name: newDisplayMember"` I searched the SO and couldn't find any satisfying answer (May be I'm wrong). This is the code snippet to load data to combo:

```
            // binding data source.
            _bsFieldList.DataSource = _dtFieldList;// _dtFieldList is a DataTable

            // Assigning binding source as the data source of the combo box.
            cboFields.DataSource = _bsFieldList;
            cboFields.DisplayMember = "FieldCaptn";
            cboFields.ValueMember = "FieldType";
```

What Am I doing wrong?

I found that using public properties for `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421546/combobox-issue-cannot-bind-to-new-value-member) this issue. But in my case this is not possible.

**EDIT:**

These are the columns of _dtFieldList

[image: columns of _dtFieldList]

Comment: The `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` should be `Column names` in your `_dtFieldList` DataTable. Could you show the columns of `_dtFieldList`?

Comment: @KingKing I have added the columns..